# ¿Cómo podría hacer una función que elimine el formato de separador de miles?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Tengo una función en JavaScript que le pone separador de miles a los números, esta es la función:

```
function formatNumber (n) {
    n = String(n).replace(/\D/g, "");
  return n === '' ? n : Number(n).toLocaleString();
}
```

Quisiera saber ¿cómo puedo hacer una función que elimine (contrareste) lo que hice con mi función formatNumber?

Comment: ¿Y qué se supone que hace tu función? Porque la verdad no le veo mucho sentido. Si se recibe un valor numérico como `1234567.89` el resultado de tu función es: `123.456.789`. Eso no es exactamente un formato válido a partir del argumento de entrada. Revisa primero que tu función realmente haga lo que necesitas. Saludos

Comment: Con la primera instrucción de esa función `n = String(n).replace(/\D/g, "");` eliminas cualquier caracter no numérico.